# Android Google Auth how to recover/refresh user token when app removed from Google account setting(Setting->Security->Manage third-party access)?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented google login inside app, so far login is working well.

The problem is that suppose i have logged in my app and then i closed app and go to Google and go to **Settings -> Security -> Manager third-party access -> MY_APP_NAME**  and then there is button which says *“REMOVE ACCESS”*  which removes access to google account to my app and all logins will become invalid. but now whenever i call  `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account,  DriveScopes.DRIVE)` this method first time throws exception `UserRecoverableAuthException`(with help of this exception user can grant permission again) but now problem is that i think this exception is only thrown one time suppose if user again *"REMOVE ACCESS"*(by above process again) then if we call `getToken` then it won't throws that exception again and returns token but if i use this token for `Google Drive` then google drive says `401 Unauthorized`.
    `{
      "code": 401,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "location": "Authorization",
          "locationType": "header",
          "message": "Invalid Credentials",
          "reason": "authError"
        }
      ],
      "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }`

So what would be best way to handle ***REMOVE ACCESS***, is handling it with `UserRecoverableAuthException` or there is other way to handle it ?

Comment: Did you give a try instead of thinking?

Comment: I am trying it from last 3 days, i have tried all possible ways like i have also tried silent login but that is not working, the only working is that  `UserRecoverableAuthException` is thrown when we call `getToken` but it not happens every time, i mean this exception is only thrown first time or after days(don't know exact) from first time throws @VVB